"snow globe" Sphere render issue
I tried to make a snow globe.
and when I got the rendered image, I can always see a weird line on middle of the sphere.
I tried both UV sphere and Quadsphere and subdivide several times but still get the same line.
is this because of unsmooth surface, light reflection other issues? thanks in advance.


I tried both quadsphere and UV sphere, got the same "line".
tried a rotated UV sphere, but got the same.

In the mesh, there is no horizontal edge at all.
confused why there is a line on the sphere.


hard to say from those 2 images, i would try to guess that you have A) Flipped normals B) duplicated vertices C) maybe there is some seam? How did you model this sphere? Your file or edit mode screenshot would help D) some hidden object that is visible in render

This could just be the reflection of the ground plane, it has a hard termination because of the curvature of the object.  Hide it in the render and see if the line persists

It may be a somewhat unrealistic effect due to how the sphere's glass surface clips through the ground, causing some strange blackface bounces, or something

YES! it's the reflection of the ground plane! but how should be solve this issue if I want to have a plane for the scene.

Solution: choose the plane > object > visibility > ray visibility > uncheck "glossy".
thank you guys!!!
